# C# compare lists List<T>

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, collections, assert

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

I want universal test method, which gets Dictionary and function, and then check equality for each dictionary entry between Value and function(Key):

```
public void TestMethod<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Func<TKey, TValue> func)
{
    foreach (var test in dict)
    {
         Assert.AreEqual(test.Value, func(test.Key));
    }
}
```

But if Values (and return value of function) is

```
List<int>
```

it doesnt work, of course. So, I found than I need

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual
```

for such cases.
But now I have to say, that my value is System.Collections.ICollection. How to do this?

Comment: I know. But I get error "Cannot convert from TValue to System.Collections.ICollection". I suppose I have to say somehow that TValue can be System.Collections.ICollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the values to `ICollection` so the compiler won't complain.

```
public void TestMethod<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Func<TKey, TValue> func)
{
    foreach (var test in dict)
    {
         if (test.Value is ICollection)
         {
              CollectionAssert.AreEqual((ICollection)test.Value, (ICollection)func(test.Key));
         }
         else
         {
              Assert.AreEqual(test.Value, func(test.Key));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, thanks! except that i need to specify System.Collections.ICollection instead of  ICollection

Comment: Good to know :)  You could add a `using System.Collections;` statement to your test class as well.